Complex constraint in a Django model
I have a use case where I want to validate that a field ForeignKey value is in a particular set, so something like:
class Role(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class Group(models.Model):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, null=False)

class Member(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_role",
                check=(
                    models.Q(role__in=... valid roles ...)
                )
            )

In other words, only allow a member to have a role if the role is listed in the roles for the group. I can't figure out how to express this.

A CheckContraint can not span multiple tables.

Any suggestions for a different approach to the problem?

Are these values char or integer? I get confused.

Sorry, I'm not understanding the question. Which values?

The value in Role model : label

You probably need to use default validators of Django

You can not do this with a CheckConstraint [Django-doc]: such constraint can span over an entire row, not over multiple tables. It thus can not "follow" ForeignKeys, or other relations.
An idea could be not to refer to a Group, or to a Role, but to the junction table that Django created for the ManyToManyField, like:
class Role(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=24)


class Group(models.Model):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, null=False)


class Member(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    group_role = models.ForeignKey(Group.roles.through, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    @property
    def group(self):
        return self.group_role.group

    @property
    def role(self):
        return self.group_role.role
It thus can only refer to records in the GroupRoles table, that thus refers to a Group and a Role, and thus the FOREIGN KEY constraint will guarantee that the role-group combination we pick implies that that Role is available for that Group.
You can monkey patch the __str__ to make it more convenient to pick the combination:
def my_str(self):
    return f'{self.role} - {self.group}'


Group.roles.through.__str__ = my_str

